# What is this yellow fungus growing under my plants?

Tags: identification, fungus

I don’t know what’s going on with my plants. Does anyone know what this? What needs to be done?

[image]

Comment: Actually, looks like slime mould. Not a problem, will change quickly.

Comment: Okay! It is worse this morning...Urgh! Can’t wait for it to go away. Thank you!

Comment: They eat microorganisms in the soil, and the shape will change quite fast, eventually will stop moving, fruit, then die and the colour fade. Fun for stop-frame photography.

Comment: I was wondering if it was slime mold.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have had this in mulch beds a few times.  I suspect it is some sort of lichen.  Harmless. I have seen this color and magenta.

Comment: Thank you! How long does it typically take to go away?

Comment: Slime mold might be the correct identification.  I always leave it alone because it looks cool.  As long as the area is not kept too damp, I think it would eventually go away.  I have never experienced it as a long term nuisance.

Answer (score 4):

It's a slime mould called *Fuligo septica*, common name dogs vomit slime mould or sometimes, scrambled egg mould. It's there because it's wet and there's plenty of dead wood in the area on the ground. When the weather or the soil/wood dries out, it will disappear - it's harmless to your plants, just looks horrible. https://www.inaturalist.org/taxa/55483-Fuligo-septica